# Rewrite URLS in Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some old SWF that has fixed links inside, so I need to rewrite all the links to redirect to new site I build on Wordpress.

I actually need to redirect all links that have FID=<123> to /me_<123> (that's the permalink I created for all pages I need to redirect)

For example:
http://kavor.org.il/KavOr07/Templates/showpage.asp?DBID=1&LNGID=2&TMID=843&FID=1997
Needs to go to http://kavor.org.il/me_1997

I tried to put this in .htaccess:
^FID=([^/.]+)/?$ /me_$1 [R]

but it has no effect and also for some reason slows down the entire site loading.
I know that Wordpress has its own rewrites so maybe it's interefering.

I would be glad for some help with that I got pretty lost in all the mod_rewrite rules...

Answer (score 0):

To match query string you will need a `RewriteCond` with `%{QUERY_STRING}`

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)FID=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^KavOr07/?$ /me_%1? [L,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Doesn't work, where do I need to place it? After the Wordpress redirect rules or before?

Comment: This should be place **before wordpress rules**